# Автоматическое определение языка браузера

Tags: django

Интересует возможность автоматически определить язык браузера пользователя, чтобы в зависимости от этого выбрать язык (если словарь для языка сгенерирован, иначе - язык по умолчанию).

В своих поисках набрёл на конструкцию, типа:

request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', None)

Которая возвращает:

ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,pl;q=0.6

при запущенном на английском языке интерфейса Chrome.

Также, мне интересно - на каждой ли странице сайта необходимо активировать язык? если я правильно понял, его можно как-то "запомнить" на время сессии пользователя.

Comment: Язык интерфейса и язык сайтов — это две **разные** настройки браузера. Очевидно, в вашем английском Chrome выбран русский язык для сайтов

Comment: В Django уже встроены механизмы для работы с локализацией и языками, и для получения текущего языка достаточно вызвать функцию `get_language()` из модуля `django.utils.translation` (при условии, что многоязычность в джанге корректно настроена). Только её результат обычно тоже опирается на значение HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE и, видимо, в вашем случае тоже получится русский — в общем, меняйте настройки браузера

Comment: @andreymal подскажете, как изменить эту настройку языка в Хроме? Сейчас мои настройки выглядят вот так, и, судя по всему, этого недостаточно:
https://clip2net.com/clip/m491909/f2fb5-clip-24kb.png

Comment: Странно, этого должно быть достаточно. Когда я выставил настройки у себя именно так, мой HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE изменился на английский язык. Перепроверьте вашу джангу ещё раз

Comment: @andreymal добавил в код

activate(get_language())

и заработало :)

А подскажете, как кооректно обработать ситуацию, когда языка браузера в сгенерированных словарях нет?
Ну и по "запоминанию" языка тоже, конечно, интересно

Comment: activate(get_language()) делать не нужно, потому что джанга делает это автоматически. Если не делает — возможно, вы забыли подключить соответствующий middleware. // При отсутствии языка будет использоваться стандартный, который вы прописали в настройке `LANGUAGE_CODE`

Comment: @andreymal вот это мои, чего-то не хватает?
https://clip2net.com/clip/m491909/eb37f-clip-9kb.png

Comment: Да вроде всего хватает, не знаю. Вообще, в любом случае get_language() абсолютно никак не влияет на значение HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, и вообще джанга никак не влияет на это значение: если там написан русский — значит хром запрашивает именно русский. Возможно, вы почистили кэш и хром уже стал запрашивать у джанги английский, а 
activate(get_language()) это всего лишь совпадение, которое нужно стереть из кода

Comment: @andreymal кстати, у меня, при открытом на Польском языке Хроме (такого перевода в Джангу не заложено), сайт открывает английский язык, хотя по умолчанию выбран русский. С чем может быть связано?

Comment: Возможно, хром опять всё закэшировал?

Comment: @andreymal кое-что другое. В Хроме есть очередь языков предпочитаемых. Я так понял, Джанго не нашел польского словаря, но зато нашел словарь для следующего языка - английского. Я их удалил и открылось "по умолчанию" на русском